# "Will you hang up?" or "Are you going to hang up?"

Tags: future, will-future

> **Phone call**
>
> Person A: "You should get some sleep."
> Person B: *(worried because they don't want person A to hang up)*
>                    "Will you/Are you going to hang up?"

What's the right way to say it?

Comment: "Please don't hang up." (Just say what you mean.)

Comment: "Will you..." sounds like a request/command to do so! "You won't hang up on me, will you?" would be one way of pleading with them not to.